# Promise remains unresolved even after handling all cases

Tags: node.js, promise, discord, discord.js

I have been writing on a Discord.JS Bot for quite a bit now, and every now and then it seems to throw me a random error / warning in console after executing one of its chat commands
(specifically `!clear`).

Now, as I already stated, the message I get in my console is a ***warning***, not an actual error, so that's not the main problem I have;

My problem lies in the execution of the command on Discord's side: Because of the unresolved, rejected promise, it will not execute `!clear` at all, leaving all messages including the command itself behind. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
if (member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) {
    channel.fetchMessages({ limit: 100 })
        .then(messages => {
            console.log(`Deleting ${messages.size} messages...`);
            channel.bulkDelete(messages).then(res => {}, err => {});
            channel.sendEmbed({
                // Success Message
            }).then(msg => msg.delete(10000), err => console.log(err));
        }, err => { console.log(err) })
} else {
    channel.sendEmbed({
        // Permission Message
    }).then(msg => msg.delete(10000), err => { console.log(err) });
}
```

As you can see, I resolved both the **success** and the **failure** state of every Promise, yet I will still see the following warning in console:

> (node:14768) Error: Bad Request *Sometimes also throws **Not Found***
>
> -- Stack Trace that only includes internal Node.JS errors --
>
> (node:14768) DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
>
> -- More Stack Trace not regarding any of my own code --

If any of you need additional code provided to answer the question, feel free to ask me and I will do so. Also, I can't +rep answers yet, but I always appreciate 'em :)

Comment: In addition to the immediate issue, as it stands `channel.sendEmbed({/*Success Message*/})` is independent of `channel.bulkDelete(messages)`, therefore the success message is not a reliable indicator of success. This is easily fixed by chaining `channel.bulkDelete(messages).then(() => channel.sendEmbed(...).then(...))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't handling the `msg.delete(10000)` rejection. You should handle it like this:

```
channel.sendEmbed({
  // Success Message
}).then(msg => msg.delete(10000)).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: @Maxx2709 I would recommend never using the second parameter of a promise's `.then(success, failure)` and instead only use `.then(success).catch(failure)`